# Mount issues with Samba under non-root user

Tags: linux, debian, centos, samba

Maybe someone can shed some light here as I'm confused.

I have this setup:

---

**Server 1 (CentOS File Server)**

- Shared directory /file/to/www/share (owned by web-user:web-user)
- Samba user "web-user" added

**Server 2 (Debian Web Server)**

- Mounted //[server]/[share] to /mnt/www_share
- Server has local user "web-user:web-user"

---

Now, (as **root**) I can access the share and Read/Write/Execute.

Though, no other users can Write (only Read/Execute).

I've tried setting the directories to 777, setting the umask in Samba to 000. I cannot mount to the share as non-root.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you include in the question the `smb.conf` from _Server 1_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike NFS (which, BTW, should have been your choice for Linux to Linux mounting), SMB doesn't automatically share user authorizations across the protocol - at least not without a complicated "Active Directory" setup.

What you probably want to do (other than change to a protocol that does share some user details, such as NFS), is to mount the directory using the required user permissions, using the `uid` and `gid` options of the `mount` command or `fstab` file.

Use `man fstab`, `man mount` (the smbfs section) and `man smbmount` for more details.

You might also be interested in investigating the `fmask` and `dmask` options.